# Sometimes get 500 Error w/ Ajax to Google Books API on production

Tags: python, heroku, flask, google-api

While working on a [small profect](http://kmagai.me/reference_gen)(Japanese) using Python, Flask, Heroku, Jquery, and Google Books API, I got 500 Internal Server Error while executing "検索", which means "search".

When you click on "検索" w/ some input on the box next to it, it sends request to the Google Books API and get books data that match to that argument via Ajax w/ Jquery as follows.

```
@app.route("/_search_books")
def search_books():
   title = request.args.get('title')
   if title:
        title = title.encode('utf-8')
        url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=' + title

        h = urlopen(url)
        data = json.load(h)

        books = []
        for i in range(len(data['items'])):
            try:
                title = data['items'][i]['volumeInfo']['title']
            except:
                title = None
            try:
                author = data['items'][i]['volumeInfo']['authors'][0]
            except:
                author = None
            try:
                publisher = data['items'][i]['volumeInfo']['publisher']
            except:
                publisher = None
            try:
                year = data['items'][i]['volumeInfo']['publishedDate']
            except:
                year = None
            try:
                thumbnail = data['items'][i]['volumeInfo']['imageLinks']['thumbnail']
            except:
                thumbnail = None
            try:
                page = data['items'][i]['volumeInfo']['pageCount']
            except:
                page = None
            books.append({'title': title, 'author': author, 'publisher': publisher, 'year': year, 'thumbnail': thumbnail, 'page': page})

        return jsonify(result=books)
```

It works properly on development, so I guess it's Google Books API's permission related stuffs or SSL related stuffs.

The weird thing is that it doesn't always return 500, and it sometimes returns expected results. It seems it's depend on the time I execute, like 200 in the morning and 500 in the afternoon.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please edit your question and include the full stack trace of the error. You may need to [enable logging](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/errorhandling/) to properly get this information. Without it there is not enough information for us to properly determine your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem.  Mine is not different between development and production; they both just occasionally return a 500.  The message is "Backend error."  I don't believe there's anything you can do to resolve this; it seems like a problem on Google's end.  I can usually repeat the same query again a few seconds later and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I actually had the same issue, changed request amount lower maxResults=15 to the search string it fixed the issue